# How can I host multiple Flask Apps for Multiple Domains on Digital Ocean?

Tags: python, nginx, dns, flask, digital-ocean

Using [this guide](http://mcktr.tl/digitalocean+flask+python+quickstart/) I created a basic Flask App in Python. This worked well, and without nginx I could connect to it using my domain. The issue is, that this wasn't scaleable to multiple apps on one droplet. To do so, I tried this:

- I connected my domain via the DNS Settings in Digital Domain, and linked my domain to to route to the IP. I did this by pointing an A record from my domain to my IP, and NS records to the Digital Ocean servers. Here are the screenshots:
  [Domain Host](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whWQd.jpg)
  [Digital Ocean DNS Host](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUsJy.jpg)
  [An example setup from the DNS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRyTl.jpg)
- I fresh installed NGINX:

  ```
  sudo aptitude install nginx
  ```
- I made `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default` this:

  ```
  upstream app_server_one {
      server 127.0.0.1:7000 fail_timeout=0;
  }

  upstream app_server_two {
      server 127.0.0.1:8000 fail_timeout=0;
  }

  server {
      listen 80 default_server;
      server_name: cloud.ajnin.me

      # [snip...]

      location / {
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
          proxy_redirect off;
          proxy_pass http://app_server_one;
      }
  }

  server {
      listen 80 default_server;
      server_name: cloud2.ajnin.me

      # [snip...]

      location / {
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
          proxy_redirect off;
          proxy_pass http://app_server_two;
      }
  }
  ```
- I started my nginx server:

  ```
  sudo service nginx start
  ```
- I created my two apps (note how both run on separate ports). Both of these run separately with nginx on default:

**app.py**

```
    from flask import Flask
    app = Flask(__name__)

    @app.route('/')
    def index():
        return 'Cloud'

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=7000, debug=True)
```

**app2.py**

```
    from flask import Flask
    app = Flask(__name__)

    @app.route('/')
    def index():
        return 'Cloud2'

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8000, debug=True)
```

- I started my two apps:

  ```
  sudo (nohup) python app.py &
  sudo (nohup) python app2.py &
  ```

Doing this, I got the Error 'This webpage is not available' from Chrome. Testing each app, it works by typing the server ip and port, but connecting with the domain doesn't seem to work. Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction to how I can make this work?

Thanks,

Aj.

UPDATE: This is the output for netstat -plunt:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
    tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1085/sshd       
    tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:7000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      25111/python    
    tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      10265/python    
    tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1085/sshd
```

UPDATE: FIXED!
See https://gist.github.com/soheilhy/8b94347ff8336d971ad0 for more info